# Moving installed instance of windows to another computer?

Tags: windows, oem, licensing

So recently i had to move my windows from one hard drive to another one, i was not worried about oem license because i was just moving it from one hard drive on the same laptop to another drive on the same laptop, now i was wondering if someone want to do this with two laptops, is it possible to re-register the moved windows to the new on using the latests activation key? (located in properties of my computer)

Comment: -1 you tagged it with clonezilla and acronis but asked nothing technical.. so it is unclear what you are asking, whether you are also puzzled about the technicalities of how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question.

If it is about moving the Windows OEM license, then yes, you can move it to a new machine - you would have to call a Microsoft automated number and dial in the installation ID.   Technically that is not allowed, but from my experience with moving (by now over 10) licenses to new motherboards, an automated call does the trick and Windows reactivates without hassle.

Comment: -1 he did tag it clonezilla so you should presume he may mean that too, though he's very unclear and it's a very badly written question you should have asked him in comment before proposing an answer, unless you were willing to also cover the technical side of how to do it too (thus covering any possibility of what he could mean), which you did not do

Comment: I agree with you; however I am not certain it is relevant. Windows OEM licenses tie up with the motherboard and from the question I gathered he was talking about license transferring. I would comment it but alas I lack the rep. If you could do this for me, I can close the answer.

Comment: what i asked was that can i move a oem licence , although it is different and a little more complicated to call automated services rather than entering a product activation key, you answered my question so i marked it as correct, as soon as i get to home i will explain more and provide pictures to get the question express my matter in a way others would understand,

Comment: Very well, glad I could help. I'll be able to expand on my answer then, as to keep with @barlop's recommendation. As for the product activation key, once you input it and try to activate Windows, you will get an error that the key is already in use on another machine. But more on that later.